# не работают медиа запросы в sass верстая по бэм

Tags: css, sass, бэм

столкнулся с такой проблемой верстая макет по БЭМ и делая медиазапросы в sass файлах:

@media (max-width: 1200px)

.interview

```
padding-right: 30px
```

и код не работает в панели разработчика как зачеркнутый

@media (max-width: 1200px)

.brif .interview

```
padding-right: 30px
```

и код работает

то есть чтобы стили применились мне нужно указать не только этот класс а еще один, более старший. хотя в видео у чувака все работает и с одни классом применяется. код как у него 1 в 1 но у меня почему-то такой баг

и это не единожды вот еще примеры:

@media (max-width: 1200px)

.interview

```
&__title

  font-size: 18px

  margin-bottom: 16px
```

не работает

.brif .interview

```
&__title

  font-size: 18px

  margin-bottom: 16px
```

работает

@media (max-width: 768px)

.cards

```
justify-content: center
```

не работает

@media (max-width: 768px)

.price .cards

```
justify-content: center
```

работает

кто может подсказать в чем причина и проблема?
сам я начинающий заманался не могу найти ответ

Answer (score 2):

Дело все из-за приоритетности. Поменяйте местами код или дайте больше вес селектору.

**Подробнее:**
Каждый селектор имеет свою массу. Самая большая масса происходить от id, маленькая от названия тега. Есть масса одинаковая, выбирается тот, какой находится в файле ниже.
Чтобы увеличить массу, достаточно указать больше информации (родителя, второй класс(если имеется) ило название тега.

**Например:**
`.cards` можно заменить на: `div.cards` или же `.cards[class]`

**Немного информации:**
1. Не важно сколько классов будет, вы не сможете переопределить селектор содержащий id, без использования `!important` или прописав в атрибут `style`.
2. Прописывать в `!important` и `style` только в случае, если никак иначе нельзя сделать.